# postgres 9.4 can't find compiled pg_rewind library

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.4

I'm running Postgres 9.4 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.3. Postgres was installed using apt-get, I downloaded the sources and dependencies with apt-get too. I downloaded pg_rewind REL9_4_STABLE branch and built it. When I try to run my pg_rewind command I get the following:

```
    The servers diverged at WAL position 0/6148D50 on timeline 1.
Rewinding from Last common checkpoint at 0/5000098 on timeline 1
SQL command failed
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rewind_support.rewind_support_ls_dir(text, boolean) RETURNS SETOF text AS '$libdir/pg_rewind_support' LANGUAGE C STRICT;
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/pg_rewind_support": No such file or directory

Failure, exiting
```

I found the pg_rewind_support.so library file and I placed it in the locations returned by pg_config --libdir and --pkglibdir with no success. I even created a copy without .so extension.

```
$ls -la $(pg_config  --pkglibdir)/pg_rewind_support*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18768 Jul 16 17:59 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/pg_rewind_support
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18768 Jul 16 17:50 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/pg_rewind_support.so
$ls -la $(pg_config  --libdir)/pg_rewind_support*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18768 Jul 16 17:59 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pg_rewind_support
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18768 Jul 16 17:44 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pg_rewind_support.so
```

Any ideas how can I make my apt-get installed Postgres recognize the pg_rewind library? I don't want to end up running in production a full postgres that was packaged and built in-house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In working through this with the OP, the steps to build pg_rewind were:

- Download the appropriate PostgreSQL 9.4.18 tarball, unpack.
- Download pg_rewind, move into contrib/
- Configure PostgreSQL to match the directory layout that Debian/Ubuntu uses:

  ./configure --libdir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib --bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin
- Do a "make" on PostgreSQL.
- Do a "make" and a "sudo make install" on pg_rewind.

`pg_rewind` must be installed on both the source system (so that the .so is available there) and on the target system (so the `pg_rewind` binary is available there).